# Public/Global Variable to send a value from two different UserForms

Tags: excel, vba

I have a table in Excel where in the Column B:B the username will be always "RESCARIZ", but i have that user variable saved on another userform which i have it set all as private: `Dim user As Variant`. I was following some docs to set it as global or at least as public to be able to send the value to the other sheet, maybe I´m incorrect about that statement.

I have it set when the userform1 initialize but no value its appearing in the textbox called UserLog.

(And the value saved on user its the `Me.txtUser.Value`)

```
    Dim FindRow
    Dim cRow As String

    cRow = user
    Set FindRow = Hoja6.Range("B:B").Find(What:=cRow, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)

    If cRow = "RESCARIZ" Then
    Me.UserLog.Text = FindRow
    End If
```

Comment: You must create a `Public` variable in a standard module, on top of it, at the declarations part! Not in the form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need a variable to be accessed from your both forms you must create one in a standard module, on top of it, in its declarations part:

`Public user As Variant`

Allocate to the variable a value in your first form code and then you can use it exactly like you tried in your code (`cRow = user`), from the second form code.

Comment: i tried setting `Option Explicit Public user As Variant` to be able to take the value from user but still not working. Apart from what you instructed me.

Comment: But, how did you test that? In principle, you will start your first form and alocate a value to the variable. Let us say `user = "TestUser"`. Then you put in the second form `Initialize` event the next code `MsgBox user`. After allocating a value to the `user` variable, using your first form, doesn't `MsgBox` retrieve its value when you load the second form? Did you put your `Public user As Variant` declaration in a standard module? Or you tried putting it in a form?

Comment: Sorry, i changed the public variable from the form to the module and now it does work. Thought i did it, but i had to double-check! Now i have a more sense of use on public and private variables and where to declare them to use them on various modules! It takes time to learn but slowly I'm understanding.

Comment: I will test with msgbox next time to check if any values are being returned.

Comment: @Santiago: Glad to be useful... It will surely work. But you must know that such a variable has a kind of volatility. I mean, if your code stops on an error you must realocate the value to it. So, it is good to check its value before using it. If this 'variable' will be all the time the same, it is recommended to use `Public Const user As String = "RESCARIZ"`. If I well understood what you do, maybe this is the way for you...

Comment: Not exactly, the user variable will check at least 10 columns which everyone will have different users on it. I thought of doing a nested if and else to be able to check the user that has logged on, in which column it's saved and bring values from that table.

Comment: OK. You know better, of course. I just started to think in that direction reading 'the username will be always "RESCARIZ"'. But, it is obvious I misunderstood your point. I wish you good luck with your project!